# Vector in vector notation

Tags: notation, vectors, convention

I'm a bit confused as far as notationally differentiating between row and column vectors goes. Suppose I define a column vector

$$\boldsymbol{a} = (a_{1}, a_{2})^{T}$$

and another column vector

$$\boldsymbol{b} = (b_{1}, b_{2})^{T} \,.$$

Say that the column vector $\boldsymbol{c}$ is given by

$$\boldsymbol{c} = (a_{1}, a_{2}, b_{1}, b_{2})^{T}\,.$$

If I wanted to write that more concisely. Would it be 
$$\boldsymbol{c} = (\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{b})^{T}$$
or
$$\boldsymbol{c} = (\boldsymbol{a}^{T}, \boldsymbol{b}^{T})^{T}\,?$$

Comment: If you want to be rigorously correct, the second one is the best option.

Comment: Why would it be more correct?

Comment: It would be more correct because $\boldsymbol{a}^T = (a_1, a_2)$ and $\boldsymbol{b}^T = (b_1, b_2)$. That being said, you can choose to abuse notation and go for the first option for simplicity, provided you warn your reader and use it consistently.

Comment: Incidentally, on the topic of keeping things simple, in TeX you don't need to enclose everything in braces. You can write `a_1` instead of `a_{1}`, for instance. You only need braces if the operator applies to more than one character, e.g., `a_{123}` produces $a_{123}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you agree with $(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2) = ((a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2))$, then it follows that

$$ \textbf{c}=(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2)^T = ((a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2))^T = (\textbf{a}^T, \textbf{b}^T)^T.$$